# Use event handlers in cloned element after removing original

Tags: javascript, jquery, packery

I have an element with properties such as drag and drop and 1 click event handler. I have cloned this element, and find that the cloned element has the event handler working, **as long as** the original element is still in the DOM. The moment I remove the original from the DOM, however, the event handler is destroyed. My code goes:

```
el = $(@id).clone(true)
$('#container').packery('addItems', el)
el.appendTo('#container')
$('#container').packery('layout')
$('#lowerContainer > ' + @id).remove()
```

The event handler on `el` works as long as the last line is not added. However, adding `$('#lowerContainer > ' + @id).remove()` kills the handler. Does anyone know how I can keep the handler in cloned element even after removing the original? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should define your click handler on container rather than on individual items:

```
$('#container').on('click', '.item', function() {...});
```

In this case it will handle clicks as on existing items as on ones added later.

Comment: syntax is wrong for event delegation, target selector should be argument of `on()`

Comment: @charlietfl indeed, fixed.